# Редактирование выбранного пункта <select> в форме

Tags: php, html, форма

Есть форма, в которой присутствуют элементы [select](/questions/tagged/select), в каждом из которых 2 пункта выбора: [включен](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd),[выключен](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd). Выбираю нужные мне пункты и отправляю все это в базу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне также необходимо иметь возможность редактировать эти данные. То есть открывать форму редактирования и вытаскивать туда данные из базы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С обыкновенными [input](/questions/tagged/input) проблем нет. Но с [select](/questions/tagged/select) у меня вышла загвоздка. Проблема в том, что я не могу при редактировании предложить те же 2 варианта, то есть один - выбранный при добавлении (по умолчанию), а второй ему противоположный.

Подозреваю, что это делается с помощью условия, но как именно - понять не могу.

Начал вот так:

```
<?
    if ($select_pay) echo "<option selected>$select_pay</option>";
?>
```

***Как вывести еще один вариант, который не был выбран при добавлении?*** В $select_pay  хранится выбранный при добавлении вариант, который я вытащил из базы.

Сам [select](/questions/tagged/select) выглядит так:

```
<select size=1 name=pay>
    <option value="Включен">Включен</option>
    <option value="Выключен">Выключен</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Если у Вас в селектах всегда гарантированно ровно два значения, разве не удобнее будет использовать вместо них чекбоксы?

Comment: Так и хотел изначально, но сказали делать на селектах, не знаю почему. Хозяин-барин.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Завести массив всех вариантов ("вкл.", "выкл.", что-то еще). В цикле `foreach` перебрать все варианты, а выбранным сделать тот, который хранится в базе.

```
$pays = array("on", "off");
foreach ($pays as $pay){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $pay; ?>" <?php if($pay == $select_pay) echo "selected"; ?>> 
<?php echo $pay; ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
}
```

Comment: Работает, большое спасибо.